# how to split the value in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

How do we split the value in an array suppose 124 into three different values 1,2,4?

I want this to be done in java.

Comment: Your question is too ill-formed to be understood.  What exactly do you mean by "in an array suppose 124"

Do you mean split a string out into an array?  Do you mean join an array into a string?

Comment: The fact that there are 3 *entirely* different answers to this question is proof that it needs a reword. Could you please rephrase your question to clarify? I don't think any of us know what you're asking.

Comment: we need more info. Please reword the question or give an example of the java code that constructs the array.

Answer (score 3):

```
String [] splits = string.split("")
```

Comment: or String.valueOf(number).split("")

Answer (score 3):

Keep dividing by 10 in a loop and take remainder : `n % 10;`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a string, then you can just take the individual characters with `getChars()`.

If it's a number then you just need to loop and use each digit individually. To start from the end you can iteratively get the last digit by `number % 10` and remove it with `number / 10`. If you start with the first digits, then you can get the digit with `number / 100`, `number / 10`, etc. and remove it with `number % 100`, `number % 10`, etc.

I'm sure you can convert that description into Java code. I'm not convinced that simply posting a bunch of code here actually helps you in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [String.getChars()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char[],%20int%29) function will give you a char[] array with one character per array element.

So you should be able to do:

```
char[] k = new char[myString.length()]
myString.getChars(0,myString.length(),k,0);
```

If you need to convert **to** an array of integers, you can add

```
int[] i = new int[k.length]
for(int j = 0; j < k.length; j++) i[j] = k[j] - '0';
```

If you need to convert **from** an integer first, just use String `myString = Integer.toString(myInt)`

Comment: Is "i[j] = '0' - k[j]" correct?  It should be fixed to i[j] = k[j] - '0'. Isn't it?